# How to control for a categorical confounding variable in statistical analysis without using parametric tests?

Tags: nonparametric, covariance, group-differences, ancova, confounding

I have around 150 variables of psychometrical data for 97 subjects (Scores and percentages of tasks, Reaction Times, and Factors, such as social-economical status of participants).

The goal of our study is to show that there is a significant difference (in many variables) between two groups:

- a clinical group (n=18), and
- a control group (n=79).

As the data are far from being normally distributed I have used a Mann-Whitney U test to compare both groups; and I have obtained significant p-values for a series of variables. The problem is that it is known that gender and age might influence the outcome of these variables. The mean and median age are the same for both groups, but gender is not balanced (there are 16 boys and 2 girls in the Clinical group; and 46 boys and 33 girls in the Control group).

What I would usually do of course is run an ANCOVA, where I would covary for gender, but the assumptions for such a model are not met (especially normality of the residuals), and, in any case, I have seen that the obtained results are very different when I use an ANOVA and a Mann-Whitney U test to compare groups.

So, to face the problem of controlling the gender confounding factor, I have thought of a few strategies, but all of them are far from being ideal:

1. Stratification. Use only boys; this way I would avoid all together the problem of correcting for the gender factor. I have done this; the problem is that for many variables the group differences are much smaller when I use only boys. Also taking the time that it has taken me to collect data, I would really prefer not to give up so many participants (girls, n=35).
2. Use ANCOVAs anyway. The problem is that the p-values differ significantly from the ones I obtain when I use a Mann-Whitney test; in particular many group differences are not visible when using such a test.
3. Transform the data, so that it becomes normal. Problem: this is not possible for many of my variables (especially when they concern scores, and most data are concentrated in one value).
4. Calculate the effect of age and gender separately. I have done this, and it gives me an overview of the variables for which gender might be a confounding factor. The problem comes when there is a difference between the control and the clinical groups but also between girls and boys; in those cases I need a way to correct for the influence of gender.
5. Use a GLM, choosing a family that more accurately models (than Gaussian distributions) the response variable. What pulls me back of this option is the fact that when I compare both groups (without covarying for gender) I obtain p-values which differ significantly from those I obtain when using Mann-Whitneys test (which I think is a bad sign, given that tests on rank tend to be quite robust)
6. Use non-quantile regression. Again, what pulls me back of this option is that p-values are quite different from those obtained with Mann-Whitneys tests. Also, I don’t know if it is the adequate strategy to test for group differences.
7. Use Robust ANCOVAs. I’ve tried using a few functions of robust ANCOVAs in R. This hasn’t been too promising for the moment because most functions in R for robust ANCOVAs expect a continuous variable and not a factor for covariation; when I have managed to covary using the gender factor, again, the results obtained are quite weird, and don’t fit well with those I originally obtained using Mann-Whitney test.

The ideal would be to obtain something that, when not covarying (just testing the differences between the clinical and the control group), would ressemble the results I obtained using the Mann-Whitney test; this way I could be reassured that covarying using such a method is ‘based’. I thought I would obtain similar values when using option 5, 6, or 7, but in fact they are quite different, which makes them hard to interpret for me.

For the moment, the best solution I can think of is comparing only boys in both groups; and for all variables for which data is close to significance, do further statistical analysis [but I don’t know what exactly I could do!]. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just for clarification: you don't mean `gender` but `sex` (biology; two possibilities: male and female). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_and_gender_distinction . It helps the reader better understand the problem and if you want to publish, this distinction is crucial.

Comment: Statistically it makes no sense include the girls she you only have 2 in the clinical group and know that sex Jean important effect modifier.